# Moving between pages using selenium without identifiers

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape https://canarabank.com/locator.aspx and some cities can have more than one page of data. But the page numbers have no tags or class names or identifiers which can be clicked. In that case, what can I use to navigate to the next page? Following is the code snippet I am using

```
class CanaraBankSpider(scrapy.Spider):
"""This class defines Canara Bank Spider."""

name = "canara_bank_ins"
URL = "https://canarabank.com/locator.aspx"

start_urls = (URL,)
brand_name = "Canara Bank"
spider_type = "chain"

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://canarabank.com/locator.aspx")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddllocater']/option[text()='Branch Details']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlstate']/option[text()='NCT of Delhi']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldistrict']/option[text()='Central Delhi']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.NAME,
                "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnview",
            )
        )
    ).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the xpath below:

```
 //a[contains(@href,'Page')]
```

This could retrieve all the links to pages. The number of these web elements would be a total number of pages-1. You can click on each link to move to each page.